# Teach prolog how to execute this simple javascript program?

Tags: javascript, prolog, logic

How to Make Prolog Intelligent Again ?

I have a JavaScript program, and my task is to turn my JavaScript source file into a working Prolog program .

In the Prolog version the JavaScript program remains unchanged but is preceded by prolog code that customizes the Prolog environment and teaches it how to do the (subsequently encountered) program in JavaScript syntax.

I have a solution that is almost working. What is missing is the ability to say 'console.log'.

## Solution in JavaScript

```
    $ node

    > function program(_)
    {
        console.log(1) ;
        console.log(2) ;
    }

    > program(_) ;
    1
    2
    undefined
    >

    ^D

    $
```

## Expected to work in Prolog

```
    $ swipl

    ?- [user] .

    /* %% insert needed solution here %% */

    ^D

    ?- [user] .

    function program(_)
    {
        console.log(1) ;
        console.log(2) ;
    }
    .

    ^D

    ?-  program(_) ; .
    1
    2
    true.

    ?-
```

## Partial solution in Prolog

```
    ?- [user] .

    :- use_module(library(clpfd)) .
    :- op(10'1,'fy','once') .
    :- op(10'1,'xfy','forall') .

/* #### goal_true_false #### */

    (
        goal_true_false(GOAL,TRUE,FALSE)
    )
    :-
    (
        GOAL *-> TRUE ; FALSE
    )
    .

/* #### op #### */

    :- op(10'1,'yf',{}) .
    :- op(10'1,'yf',';') .
    :- op(10'1,'xfy',';') .
    :- op(10'1,'fy','function') .


/* #### semicolon #### */

    (
        semicolon(A,OUT)
    )
    :-
    (
        OUT
        =
        (
            goal_true_false(A,(true),(throw({ problem: false , culprit: (A) , reporter: ';' })))
        )
    )
    .

    (
        goal_expansion(IIN,OUT)
    )
    :-
    (
        IIN
        =
        (
            A ; B ; C 
        )
        ,
        semicolon(A,A_SEMICOLON)
        ,
        semicolon(B,B_SEMICOLON)
        ,
        OUT
        =
        (
            A_SEMICOLON , B_SEMICOLON ; C
        )
    )
    .

    (
        goal_expansion(IIN,OUT)
    )
    :-
    (
        IIN
        =
        (
            A ; B ;
        )
        ,
        semicolon(A,A_SEMICOLON)
        ,
        semicolon(B,B_SEMICOLON)
        ,
        OUT
        =
        (
            A_SEMICOLON , B_SEMICOLON
        )
    )
    .

    (
        goal_expansion(IIN,OUT)
    )
    :-
    (
        IIN
        =
        (
            A ; B
        )
        ,
        semicolon(A,A_SEMICOLON)
        ,
        semicolon(B,B_SEMICOLON)
        ,
        OUT
        =
        (
            A_SEMICOLON , B_SEMICOLON
        )
    )
    .

    (
        goal_expansion(IIN,OUT)
    )
    :-
    (
        IIN
        =
        (
            A ;
        )
        ,
        semicolon(A,A_SEMICOLON)
        ,
        OUT
        =
        (
            A_SEMICOLON
        )
    )
    .

/* #### function SIGNATURE { BODY } #### */

    term_expansion(IIN,OUT)
    :-
    (
        IIN
        =
        (
            function SIGNATURE { BODY }
        )
        ,
        OUT
        =
        (
            SIGNATURE :- ( BODY )
        )
    )
    .

/* #### console_log #### */

    function console_log(IT)
    {
        once
        (
            writeq(IT)
            ,
            nl
        )
    }
    .

    ^D
```

### Testing

I deliberately use `console_log` for this solution instead of `console.log`
because I don't know yet what to do to make `console.log` work.

```
    ?- [user] .

    function program(_)
    {
        console_log(1) ;
        console_log(2) ;
    }

    .

    ^D

    ?- program(_) ; .
    1
    2
    true.
```

What remains to be done is to figure out what to do about the `.` in `console.log`.

Can anyone help?

Also , I am curious for opinions about the above implementation of semicolon. Do you think that a semantic such as that for `;` is an appropriate match to the semiotic expectations inherent in the typical computer programming script?

Comment: Just FYI, you're relying on a bit of the Node REPL there in your JavaScript example. When you call `program(_);`, in a normal environment, `_` would not be defined. It's only defined in Node's REPL because it's a REPL thing: The value of the last result. If you ran that code *not* in Node's REPL, it would fail with a ReferenceError ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/m6tvxcft/)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : thanks , I did not realize that .  The `_` is only there because it is a requirement of prolog .  prolog barfs whenever it encounters `()` . In prolog you replace `()` with <nothing>  , i.e you could do `function program { ...}` , and invoke it like `program ; .` .

Comment: In prolog `"_"` means "the variable that never gets a value" . Thus in the case of prolog `program(_) ;` means `invoke the function "program" and give it 1 argument , the argument is the throwaway variable "_"` .. In javascript `"_"` is (more simply and generically) an identifier , thus `program(_)` means `invoke the function "program" and give it 1 argument , the argument is the value found using identifier "_"` .

Comment: To avoid the Node dependency, I suggest passing JavaScript's version: `undefined`. E.g.: `program(undefined);` (or, really, anything else).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : you are right , passiing undefined is the right thing to do .